# How to trigger action when textfield becomes active

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, custom-cell

I have a CollectionViewController made up of custom cells. At this point my custom cells are only made up of UITextFields. When I click inside one of the textFields to begin typing I want to trigger an animation on the cell. For some reason I can't figure out why my animation isn't being triggered when I click inside the textField. When I conform to the UItextFieldDelegate protocol and try to trigger the action through the DidBeginEditing method it doesn't work. When I try to trigger the animation through UIControlEvents.touchDown it isn't working either.

```
@objc func animateCell(textField: UITextField) {  
    print("TextField active")
   let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: ({
   cell?.frame = collectionView.bounds
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
  }), completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Do any of the text field delegate methods work?  how & where did you set up the UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: I made the CustomCollectionViewCell the UITextFieldDelegate. They do but apparently the didBeginEditing method doesn't get called until you start typing. I need the animation to trigger as soon as I click inside the textField. @MichaelDautermann

Comment: try shouldBeginEditing instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, [try using `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619601-textfieldshouldbeginediting) (and make sure to return `true` from that method since you want to allow the user to type :-).

Also, since you say the method doesn't fire until you click on a different textfield outside of the first one selected, fire the animation manually for the initially selected text field as the collection view is displayed.

Comment: The documentation for `textFieldDidBeginEditing` states: *"This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just became the first responder."*. So it is called when the text field gains focus, not when the user actually starts typing.

Comment: Hmm ok that must be where my problem actually lies then @rmaddy. Guess I'll look into that.

Comment: Thats not working either, that method doesn't trigger until I click into a different textField/cell. @MichaelDautermann

Comment: @MichaelDautermann the only problem with triggering the animation manually as the collectionView is displayed is that I have 100 cells in my collection view and I need to animation to trigger for each of them when they're selected individually.

Comment: I only said to trigger it manually for the first one (since it sounds like the first cell may have its text field set as first responder as the collection view first appears).  Then `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` should trigger your animations as the user clicks from cell to cell.  Or do I misunderstand your UI totally?

Comment: Ah ok I was misunderstanding your thought process there. I think that will actually work, I'll just have to adjust my animation. @MichaelDautermann

Comment: That worked @MichaelDautermann But apparently it actually will fire on the first cell as long as I click somewhere else on the CollectionViewController before selecting one of the cells...

Comment: whew! that's a relief and I'm glad it's working. Usually when @rmaddy speaks up, I know my answer is in trouble.